# JPA criteria api how refactor query from OneToMany to OneToMany(OneToMany)

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I needed to change my Entity from

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    Set<Option> options; 

}
```

to

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    List<OptionGroup> options; 

}
```

With

```
@Entity
public class OptionGroup{

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Option> options; 

}
```

My problem is to refactor a query respectively a Predicate that returned all entities with same list of options. This is working fine and my hope is to just refactor it to operate on "OptionGroup" instead of "SomeEntity" as before.

The predicate signature was:

```
private Predicate matchAllOptions(Set<Option> set, CriteriaBuilder cB, CriteriaQuery<SomeEntity> query)
```

My idea is to change it to

```
private Predicate matchAllOptions(Set<Option> set, CriteriaBuilder cB, Root<OptionGroup>, CriteriaQuery<OptionGroup> query)
```

And call this from a method where i create an and predicate of all. But with this i am struggling:

```
    private Predicate matchAllOptionGroups(List<OptionGroup> list, Root<OptionGroup> root, CriteriaBuilder cB, Root<SomeEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<SomeEntity> query) {
    
    Predicate predicate;

    ListAttribute<SomeEntity, OptionGroup> optionGroupAtt = SomeEntity_.optionGroups;
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        //??? how to join
        ListJoin<SomeEntity, OptionGroup> join = root.join(optionGroupAtt);
        
        //how to use join here
        Predicate[] match = list.stream().map(OptionGroup::getOptions)
                .map(options-> matchAllOptions(options, cB, ????, ????))
                .toArray(Predicate[]::new);
        
        predicate = cB.and(match);
    } else {
        // if given list is empty match with empty list in db
        predicate = cB.isEmpty(root.get(optionGroupAtt));

    }
    return predicate;
}
```

so how to call matchAllOptions from within matchAllOptionGroups? How to get Root and CriteriaQuery. Or is it needed that i change "matchAllOptions"?